# In Scala.js facades, why does the @js.native annotation preclude the @JSExport one?

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

Please consider a Scala.js library with a native dependency implemented as pure JavaScript CommonJS module.

The library includes a facade for the JavaScript dependency.  As expected, the facade includes a lot of code like:

```
@JSImport("com", "Foo") @js.native
class Foo extends js.Object { ... }
```

Unfortunately, the ScalaJS-Bundler bundles Foo in a way that hides it from the global scope.  The obvious fix involves adding the @JSExport annotation to the other two, but that results in a compiler error.

Why isn't js.native compatible with JSExport?  What would it take to add support for @JSExport on facades?

Is any work-around available now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@JSExport` on top-level classes and objects was deprecated [in Scala.js 0.6.15](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2017/03/21/announcing-scalajs-0.6.15/). What you are after is actually `@JSExportTopLevel`.

There is no fundamental reason that `@JSExportTopLevel` is not compatible with `@JSImport`/`@JSGlobal`. It isn't because of the 3 following things:

- supporting it means more work in the entire compiler toolchain to support it,
- it felt like a rare use case, and
- there is another way to achieve the same result.

The other way to achieve the result is simply to export a `val` storing the result of the import, as follows:

```scala
@js.native
@JSImport("com", "Foo")
class Foo extends js.Object { ... }

// 'private' not to pollute the Scala API with this object
private object Reexports {
  @JSExportTopLevel("Foo") // or another name
  val Foo = js.constructorOf[Foo]
}
```

It sure is a bit more verbose if you only re-export one such import, but you can bundle as many as you want in the unique `object Reexports`.